# How can i get the Image Id in c#, from Repeater?

Tags: .net

How can i get the Image Id in c#, from Repeater ? Here I am using a repeater to display the images . How can i get this Image Id from codebehind ? Thank you

Comment: Which id you want to get? The codebehind is usually invoked after some action is performed. Is the click of the image?

Comment: ya . I added tags for that Image when i click on that image tag new image will display just like this . http://tympanus.net/Development/ImageZoomTour/

Answer (score 0):

You use the `ClientID` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the asp.net Image control for your images you can find them using `.FindControl` For example:

```
Image findImg = (Image)myRepeater.items[x].FindControl("imgID");
```

.Items[x] is where x is the index of the specific itemTemplate instance. The index starts from 0.